# Non-jQuery: Getting height even if the max-height is zero

Tags: javascript

This code is working fine.

What I am doing here is exaggerating the max-height of class active but what I need is to specify the exact height to be able to run the effect at the same speed.

For this example. I don't write a dynamic navbar and this is lack of condition but I think it covers what I want to specify.

If you click the w33racle, you'll see in console that there's a number. However, 0 is not the value I needed. I want it to be the height of ul.dropdown.active regardless of whether or not it has the .active class

```js
let test_clicker = document.getElementById('testClicker');

test_clicker.onclick = (e) => {
  let self = e.target || e.srcElement,
      s_s = self.nextElementSibling.classList;
  
  s_s.contains('active') ? s_s.remove('active') : s_s.add('active');
  
  console.log(self.nextElementSibling.clientHeight);
}
```

```css
.dropdown {
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out; }

.dropdown.active {
  max-height: 500px; }
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <a id="testClicker">w33racle</a>
    <ul class="dropdown">
      <li><a>This</a><li>
      <li><a>is</a><li>
      <li><a>for</a><li>
      <li><a>sample</a><li>
      <li><a>only</a><li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily get it by the adding the height of the children.

Take advantage of what javascript gave you. You don't need `animationend` in this case.

```js
let test_clicker = document.getElementById('testClicker'),
    thisIsTheHeight = 0;

test_clicker.onclick = (e) => {
  thisIsTheHeight = 0;
  let self = e.target || e.srcElement,
      s_s = self.nextElementSibling.classList;
  
  s_s.contains('active') ? s_s.remove('active') : s_s.add('active');
  
  [].forEach.call(self.nextElementSibling.children, (elem) => {
    thisIsTheHeight += elem.clientHeight;
  });
  
  console.log(thisIsTheHeight);
}
```

```css
.dropdown {
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out; }

.dropdown.active {
  max-height: 500px; }
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <a id="testClicker">w33racle</a>
    <ul class="dropdown">
      <li><a>This</a><li>
      <li><a>is</a><li>
      <li><a>for</a><li>
      <li><a>sample</a><li>
      <li><a>only</a><li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that the JavaScript finishes before your CSS transition is finished playing.

[Look into the "transitionend" event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/transitionend)

A quick fix would be to either remove the CSS transition, or add a setTimeout with a delay equal to the length of the CSS transition. However, I recommend the using the transitionend event if it is fitting.

EDIT with implementation example:

```js
let test_clicker = document.getElementById('testClicker');

test_clicker.onclick = (e) => {
  let self = e.target || e.srcElement,
      s_s = self.nextElementSibling.classList;
  
  s_s.contains('active') ? s_s.remove('active') : s_s.add('active');

}

document.querySelectorAll("ul.dropdown").forEach(function(element){
  element.addEventListener("transitionend", function(){
    console.log(element.clientHeight);
    console.log("transition ended")
  });
});
```

```css
.dropdown {
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out; }

.dropdown.active {
  max-height: 500px; }
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <a id="testClicker">w33racle</a>
    <ul class="dropdown">
      <li><a>This</a><li>
      <li><a>is</a><li>
      <li><a>for</a><li>
      <li><a>sample</a><li>
      <li><a>only</a><li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: `transitionend` is the way to go. You should not and cannot trust on a timeout to be sure the transition acutally ended

Comment: @HermLuna - Of course, before the class is added, the height will still be 0... See my edited answer, perhaps it is clear now what I meant?

Comment: @HermLuna - Edited again to fix a mistake. I use querySelectorAll in case you have multiple dropdowns on the page, but this is just an example to show you what I mean.

Comment: You said you wanted it to always give you the height of ul.dropdown, which dynamically changes. You did not say you always wanted it to give you the expanded height.

Comment: The height of ul.dropdown is not always 180. When it doesn't have the .active class, the height is indeed 0. If the other answer is what you were looking for, I understand your question now, no worries. :)

I would have said, "I want it to be the height of ul.dropdown.active regardless of whether or not it has the .active class"